# Make searching more convenient

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface, android-app

If you want to search in the app, you need to navigate to the landing page for the target site. This is a slow process if the one you want isn't in your favorites list. It also results in potentially needless API calls to load the page's data.

Adding a search option to the navigation menu would be a huge boost in productivity for those of us who search frequently. But how to determine from that context which site to search? I suggest a dropdown that selects a default in the following order of preference:

- the current site
- the first site in the user's favorites list
- the site where the user has the highest rep

Space is at a higher premium in the menu than in most other places, so how to compactly display which site is selected? A two line widget seems wasteful, or at least inelegant. A watermark textbox could display the site name. If the name is too lengthy (e.g. English Language Learners), it could be shortened to the subdomain.

Here's what I'm picturing:

```
 ___________________________
| O | *search meta SE*  | v |
-----------------------------
```

The magnifying glass is on the left to match the other icons' placement and to prevent tap conflation with the list chevron.